# Find the minimum distance to a set

Tags: r, data.table

I have two sets, A and B, both containing positions of some particles. What I want to do is the following:

```
For each element a in A, 
    Calculate the minimum distance between a and the elements of B.
Put these distances in to a list and return.
```

I know how to do this with looks, but I don't know how to do it in a fast way using `data.table` syntax.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?  I'm guessing A and B are supposed to be individual data.tables but are a and b supposed to represent the position or is that the id of the particle and the position is represented in some other way?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor no, A and B individual columns of a single data.table

Comment: Thanks for removing the `Rcpp` tag, @coatless.  Was about to do the same...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to loop over 'A', get the `min` `abs`olute difference from the 'B' vector and store as a `vector`

```
sapply(A, function(x) min(abs(x - B)))
```

Or with `data.table` syntax

```
dt1[, lapply(A, function(x) min(abs(x - B)))]
```

---

If the vectors are sorted, a fast option is `findInterval`

```
A[findInterval(A, B)]
```

---

If these are columns of `data.table`

```
dt1[, A[findInterval(A, B)]]
```

---

Or using `outer`

```
outer(A, B, FUN = function(x, y) min(abs(x - y)))
```

Comment: Do you happen to know whether `sapply` or `outer` is faster?

Comment: @Our yes, `outer` is faster assuming memory is not a constraint

Comment: Maybe a quick question: instead of returning the minimum, what if I wanted to return the second smallest distance? How could I do that in a fast way?

Comment: @Our Probably, you need `sort(abs(x-B))[2]`

Comment: Cool! Solution gallery!

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `expand.grid` + `aggregate`

```
aggregate(cbind(d = abs(A - B)) ~ A, expand.grid(A = A, B = B), min)
```

gives

```
> aggregate(cbind(d = abs(A - B)) ~ A, expand.grid(A = A, B = B), min)
          A           d
1 0.2016819 0.004292644
2 0.2655087 0.059534088
3 0.3721239 0.011979819
4 0.5728534 0.056260681
5 0.9082078 0.009818105
```

## Data

```
set.seed(1)
A <- runif(5)
B <- runif(10)
```

Comment: Is this method faster than that of the other answer?

Comment: @Our I guess `outer` could be faster, but you can try both and see the performance.